# Include 'Select Image' box with LaTeX

Tags: hyperref, forms, eforms

I am wondering if there is a package in LaTeX which will allow me to include 'Select Image' box into the document (see below) with which the user of the PDF can upload an image. I believe the document was created with one of the Adobe Products:

[image: Select Image Box in PDF]

Comment: I showed some code here once https://texnique.fr/osqa/questions/10834/formulaire-pdf-avec-image-modifiable (the first line is no longer needed in a current LaTeX)

Comment: Thank you. Will give it a try.